# What is the SNMP OID to fetch the ports assigned to VLANs?

Tags: snmp

I got a interface index of the vlan interface over SNMP. like this:
  IF-MIB::ifDescr.952 = STRING: Vlan-interface310

How can I get what physical interface in this vlan-interface.

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question, so that everyone can see the image correctly.

Comment: Get `IF-MIB:ifStackStatus.952` . Index after `952` in result will give ifIndex of next layer in network stack hierarchy (although not necessarily physical interface ifIndex). Read more in `IF-MIB:ifStackTable` definition.